# How to setup monorepo for vue ecosystem with NX?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, monorepo, nomachine-nx

is there a way to setup monorepo tools like NX with vue3?
I've seen the unofficial repo that can be added to NX for handling vue, but the support is not that great. Is there any other package that can handle vue & vite officially?

This is what I hope the packages more or less:

- Vue 3
- Vite
- Vitest
- Storybook
- Tailwind
- Tanstack (tbd, but if that match big plus)

I've try setup the NX for vue, but somehow is not that great and the version that requirement was too old (currently need 15.0, but now NX have 15.9)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to answer the same question, and the best solution I found for me is to use the NX React plugin(@nrwl/react) and replace all React stuff with Vue.

Also there is another plugin provided by community [vue3-vite](https://github.com/samatechtw/nx-vue3-vite/tree/main/packages/vue3-vite), but I'm still not happy with it

Comment: Thank you, but the experience I have after implementing it is not that good, the code generation ofc that wont runnning and also seems its better implement it using pnpm instead nx

Answer (score 0):

[With the release of Nx 17.0, Vue is officially supported.](https://blog.nrwl.io/nx-17-0-has-landed-1dad19176ff3)